# JavaFX functions do not work even though there are no errors

Tags: java, javafx

I'm following a tutorial loosely by thenewboston and I'm running into a bit of a roadblock. To my understanding the ID in the .JFXM file is equivalent to a variable in the controller class. The onAction command is a reference to a function in the controller class.

The tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMdjhuYSrqg

What I don't understand:

1. Why I need to initialize the variable `public Button loginBtn = new Button();` when in the tutorial he does not.
2. Why does setText do nothing `loginBtn.setText("aahh!");`
3. If I wanted to get text from a field, I would use `System.out.println(FXuserLoginName.getText());` Which results in an error if the variable is not initialized. If It IS initialized, nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class Jfx extends Application {
    public Button loginBtn = new Button();
    TextField FXuserLoginName;
    PasswordField userLoginPassword;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));    
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,208,208);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Odin");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void ActionloginButton() {//logs into database, loginButton is connected to Login.fxml there #loginButton is present
        loginBtn.setText("aahh!");
        System.out.println("Login button..");
        //System.out.println(FXuserLoginName.getText());
        System.out.println("Got text");
    }
}
```

And here is my Controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Jfx">
   <children>
      <TextField id="FXuserLoginName" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="37.0" promptText="Username" />
      <PasswordField id="userLoginPassword" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="76.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" promptText="Password" />
      <Button id="loginBtn" layoutX="81.0" layoutY="113.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" onAction="#ActionloginButton"/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to use the application class as controller class. You'll end up with 2 different instances. The code shown seems correct though. Have you changed the visibility of the field? For debugging purposes you could add a method `@FXML private void initialize() {}` and set a breakpoint in there/add the appropriate prints. Check, if the `loginBtn` is part of a scene at that time (does `Node.getParent` return `null`). Which version of Java(FX) are you using btw?

Comment: You have `id` instead of `fx:id`. Once you make those changes, revert everything so that it matches the examples you have seen, and as Fabian says, don’t use the Application class as the Controller class.

Comment: @James Thank you SO much!!!! Also, Application is the package and Jfx is the controller class. Can you please explain a bit further?

Comment: @AndyKrauland I don’t think there’s anything else to explain. You have `id = ...` instead of `fx:id = ...`.

Comment: @AndyKrauland Regarding the `Application ` and controller, you are using the `Application` *class* as the controller. Your `Jfx` class *is a* `Application`. Your package is `application` (not `Application`). You should create a separate controller class that is not the `Application`.